# looking for twitter api create favorite rate limit

Tags: twitter

I tried to find information on the maximum number of tweets/statuses you can favor using the twitter api but couldn't find any information.

This is the post to use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/favorites/create

Does anyone know the limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not precised but experimentally, it looks like around 1000 per day.

Comment: FWIW, I started getting 429 status codes around 600 in an hour.

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly there isn't one but I've received a message stating this recently.

> It's great that you like so many updates, but we only allow so many
>   updates to be marked as a favorite per day. (More info can be found
>   here
>   http://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following)